# 12v PNP- switching with MCU

Tags: microcontroller, 12v, pnp

Hey I got a question about switching a 12V supply to a low power circuit with an MCU.

My requiaments are:
 - switching has to be on the High side.
 - switch should stay "closed" when MCU is powered down.
 - MCU is TTl level (Atmega 328P)

After some searching I came up with this shematic but I don't know if it is ok to conect the 12V supply with an Voltage dividor to the MCU.

[image: PNP with MCU]

Answer (score 1):

The voltage divider R2-R3 doesn't hurt but normally (i.e. if the ouput is configured to drive high and low; not just low) it is not needed.

It may be needed though, if you want to the signal level at the gate of the MOSFET to be high when the MCU's output is in  high impedance state (e.g. during reset).

Comment: There should be a resistor between base and drain to limit the base current. Having another resistor going from drain to +12V would be a good idea (to avoid the base dangeling around when the MOSFET is off). Having the MCU output pulled by one resistor to +5V is about as good as having it pulled by the voltage divider (to +4.8V). Maybe there is a reason to pull it to the +12V power source because it is earlier/longer available as the +5V power source at power up/down.

Comment: Ok I added a 10k res between base-PNP and +12V. 
The resaon for the divider instead of a res to +5V is that the 12V and 5V a turned on/off independently. And the MCU should be able to overwrite that status.

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense. But if +5V is off and +12V is on be aware  what Andy aka is mentioning: +4.8V at the ouput of an unpowered IC (MCU) may try to power the +5V circuit via the internal protection diode of the IC (=bad). It is no poblem, however, if the MCU is powered but in reset state.

Comment: uhh I forgot about the internal protection diodes. that would be very bad.... well I guess I dismiss my first Idea....

Answer (score 1):

I'd be a little concerned that the resistor potential divider might back-power the supposedly shut-down MCU (via its output) and strange things may happen to the MCU. Just a gut-feeling. I'd be happier with this sort of circuit: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fClpej.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The line from the MCU to M2's gate has to be positively driven to turn off Q1. I'm not saying it's perfect or minimal but I would be happier with this type of approach in that there are fewer uncertainties.

Q1 can be replaced with a p ch MOSFET (with a slight modification) and, if the supply voltage was greater than 12 volts (closer to 20 volts) a zener diode would be needed across R1 to protects M1's gate from over stress.

Comment: I acutally thought of that, but than I remembert that I already had a voltage detection voltage dividor on a seperat pin on my MCU... so... I guess I will do some reseach into backpowering my MCU. 3 Tranys to achieve such an easy task seems a little bit too much. And I would also need a diverent circuit for the voltage detection...

Comment: @kraxi well, you could use a relay with NC contact.